# Help writing trigger to update unrelated field

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

*******************UPDATED*******************************
I finally got the code to compile, but now it isn't working, so there must be an issue in my logic.  Any input would be appreciated.

```
trigger CallDispositionOnCampaignMember on Task (before insert) {

//pull campaign member list

list<CampaignMember> myCampaignMembers = new list<CampaignMember>();
myCampaignMembers = [Select ID, Call_Disposition__c From CampaignMember];

//pull task list

list<Task> myTasks = new list<Task>();
myTasks = [Select ID, Campaign_Member_ID__c, Call_Disposition__c From Task Where Campaign_Member_ID__c != null];

//map tasks list to use campaign member as key

map<string,Task> memIDtoTaskMap = new map <string,Task>();
for (Task t: myTasks){
 memIDtoTaskMap.put(t.Campaign_Member_ID__c, t );
 }

//Matching with list and map by campaign member id

for (CampaignMember a: myCampaignMembers){
  if (memIDtoTaskMap.containsKey(a.id))
 {
      a.Call_Disposition__c = memIDtoTaskMap.get(a.id).Call_Disposition__c;
     update MyCampaignMembers;
  }
```

Comment: HI Lori, From you question this is what I am understanding, there is  field on CampaignMeber and you were updating it when a new task is created. but when I look into your code I am bit confused. when new task is created in CampaignMember of specific record type you are updating the task field. so what I am going to do is I will post two pieces of code in few minutes, choose which fits better into your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Has I mentioned in my comment I posted code here.
you can follow the below link to improve you trigger coding skills.
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

//if your requirement is to update field on campaignmember

trigger CallDispositionOnCampaignMember on Task (after insert) {

```
schema.describesobjectresult taskRecordType=CampaignMember.sobjecttype.getdescribe();
map<string,schema.recordtypeinfo> taskRecordTypeMap=taskRecordType.getrecordtypeinfosbyname();
id taskRecordTypeId= taskRecordTypeMap.get(**your Record Type Name**).getrecordtypeid();

Map<Id, CampaignMember> cmpList =new Map<Id, CampaignMember>();
cmpMap= [Select Id, CallDisposition__c from CampaignMember where Id];
List<CampaignMember> cmpUpdateList= new  List<CampaignMember>();

for (Task t : Trigger.new) {

    IF (t.RecordTypeId = taskRecordTypeId && cmpMap.get(t.whatId) != null){

        CampaignMember cmbr=new CampaignMember();
        cmbr.Id = t.WhatId;

        //If you are updating the CampaignMember

        cmbr.Call_Disposition__c = **Value**; // desired value to be assigned.
    }
cmpUpdateList.add(cmbr);
if(!cmpUpdateList.isEmpty())
    update cmpList;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you!  This is my first attempt at a trigger, and I found myself very confused.  I am indeed trying to update a field on the campaign member when a new task is created that is a specific record type, not just when any task is created.

Comment: Then Lori, 90% of your trigger is ready. Make changes at the starred or bold places, there may be some small typo errors or compile errors, if you can fix thats fine if not keep posting I will help you.

Comment: So, this is what I have and am getting expecting a semicolon, found 'cmpMap' at line 8 column 0

Comment: trigger CallDispositionOnCampaignMember on Task (after insert) {

schema.describesobjectresult taskRecordType=CampaignMember.sobjecttype.getdescribe();
map<string,schema.recordtypeinfo> taskRecordTypeMap=taskRecordType.getrecordtypeinfosbyname();
id taskRecordTypeId= taskRecordTypeMap.get(CampaignCall).getrecordtypeid();

Map<Id, CampaignMember> cmpList =new Map<Id, CampaignMember>()
cmpMap = [Select Id, CallDisposition__c from CampaignMember where Id];
List<CampaignMember> cmpUpdateList= new  List<CampaignMember>();

for (Task t : Trigger.new) {

Comment: IF (t.RecordTypeId = taskRecordTypeId && cmpMap.get(t.whatId) != null){

        CampaignMember cmbr=new CampaignMember();
        cmbr.Id = t.WhatId;

    
        cmbr.Call_Disposition__c = t.Call_Disposition__c;    }
cmpUpdateList.add(cmbr);
if(!cmpUpdateList.isEmpty())
    update cmpList;
}
}

Comment: ok I am updating the answer with semi colon. every statement in apex should be terminated with a ;.

Answer (score -1):

You should modify your code as follows:-

1. Retrieve required CampaignMember records in trigger (query them and add them to a map). Upon retrieval, update them in your current loop to update the values
2. Do not hardcode RecordType Id in there, instead use RecordType name or retrieve record types via query and then use it for comparison. ID should not be hardcoded in code.

So, your assignment code should be like (sample, not complete):-

```
Map<ID, CampaignMember> mapMembers = new Map<ID, Campaignmember<({<SOQL Query>});
RecordType recType = [<SOQL Query>];

for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
    if (<CONDITION>){
        CampaignMember member = mapMembers.get(t.CampaignMember)
        member.CallDisposition__c = t.Call_Disposition__c; 
    }
}
```